# SQL query optimization on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a SQL query that is taking too much time to execute. How can I optimize it so that it should not take much time it is taking around 620sec that means 10 min.

```
| 190543 | root | localhost | ischolar | Query   |  620 | Copying to tmp table                                                                                                 
 
SELECT a.article_id, count(a.article_id) AS views
FROM timed_views_log a
INNER JOIN published_articles pa
    ON (a.article_id = pa.article_id)
WHERE
    a.date BETWEEN date_format(curdate() - interval 1 month,'%Y-%m-01 00:00:00') AND
    date_format(last_day(curdate()-interval 1 month),'%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')
GROUP BY a.article_id
ORDER BY
    views desc
LIMIT 6, 5;
```

Comment: You specify SQL Server in your title, but use MySQL syntax in your query - and tag both - which is it?

Comment: Please check article_id in published_articles and make it index if not already

Comment: I have edited the title to reflect MySQL, as the syntax used in the question is 100% MySQL (and not SQL Server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try adding indices which target the join and where conditions:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON timed_views_log (date, article_id);
CREATE INDEX idx2 ON published_articles (article_id);
```

The first index, if used, should speed up the `WHERE` clause by allowing MySQL to use only the index to satisfy your filters on the date.  The second index should allow MySQL to do the lookup for the join faster.

Comment: Could you please elaborate.

Comment: Unfortunately, giving a full explanation of how a SQL index works is out of scope for a single answer.  You may wish to review the basics of indexing in SQL.

Comment: @AKASH Out of curiosity, how much slower is it with `CREATE INDEX idx1 ON timed_views_log (article_id,date);` instead?

Comment: @AKASH But that's not Strawberry's question.  He (it?) is asking what happens to performance if you _switch_ the order of the two columns in the index.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL server you can use sql server query execution plan and optimizations suggested by it.
reference article - https://www.sqlshack.com/using-the-sql-execution-plan-for-query-performance-tuning/

your query is a join with where clause, so mostly the data in the tables itself is large, try adding index.